# Is there any way can make a cocoa application which use base SDK 10.10 can run correctly in OS X 10.9

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have created a cocoa application which used the base SDK OS X 10.10. Some APIs which only exists in 10.10 are called. So it doesn't run correctly in the system which version is lower than 10.10.

So, i wan't to know is there any way can make my application run correctly in OS X 10.9 except rewrite it use lower SDK.? If not, What is the value of these new API. because i can't use it. If i used it application can't work in lower system.

Thanks!

Comment: **NO**, you should read this article, however this is not for Yosemite but for snow-leopard, but it will clear your doubts...[Building for Older OS](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/09/building-for-earlier-os-versions-in.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use 10.10 as your Base SDK, and set your deployment platform to 10.9. You can then use `respondsToSelector:` and `NSClassFromString` to know if the class/method you're trying to use is available on the current OS, and degrade gracefully (for example, only make a feature available if you're running on the latest OS).

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd have to rewrite it to use API calls which are available in 10.9.

The point of adding new calls to the API is because eventually everyone will have a device running the newer software - especially with Apple products - and then you'll be able to use it. Also, some people don't mind not being able to run on an older device. If they never added anything to the API then we would still be using the same things from 20 years ago.

If you think this is bad then try writing software for Android. [The majority of devices are still running old API versions.](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the answer is NO. You can't make an app which is built using the latest API's for 10.10 run in 10.9.

What the value of using the latest API's is depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to take advantage of the latest Apple technologies like iCloud Drive and CloudKit then you need 10.10. However, if your project doesn't need the these technologies then it may be worth making your app using a lower SDK.

It's worth noting that OS X 10.10 is free so you probably won't be alienating anyone by using the latest SDK. It's a different story for iOS where usually only the latest few iPhone and iPad models can be upgraded (e.g. iOS 8 from iPhone 4S and upwards).

Hope this helps.